# How to display loader symbol ONLY beside a specific item which was clicked in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The problem here is, the loader symbol is getting displayed beside every item in the ng-repeat array. How can I display the loader symbol just beside the item which was ***clicked***

I tried using `$index` but no luck.

I created a working example using [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/KKPQoNy). Could anyone please guide how to do it.

Below are excerpts from my app.

**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
  <li class="listItems" ng-repeat="user in userDetails">
    {{user.name}}, {{user.job}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok markAsChecked" ng-click="markAsChecked()"></span>
    <span ng-show="isLoaderActivated" class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat loader"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS Code**

```
 $scope.markAsChecked = function() {
   console.log("clicked");
   $scope.isLoaderActivated = true;
   $timeout(function() {
     return ($scope.isLoaderActivated = false);
   }, 2000);
 };
```

Comment: Your scope needs to be able to store which item was clicked: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/VwZQXRa

Comment: @ChrisG Awesome, that was it. Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find solution [CodePan](https://codepen.io/vishuminhas/pen/RwbQdqR)

**Html Code**

```
<ul>
 <li class="listItems" ng-repeat="user in userDetails">
{{user.name}}, {{user.job}}
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok markAsChecked" ng-click="markAsChecked(user)"></span>
<span ng-show="user.isLoaderActivated" class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat loader"></span>
```

**JS Code**

```
 $scope.markAsChecked = function(item) {
console.log("clicked");
item.isLoaderActivated = true;
$timeout(function() {
  item.isLoaderActivated = false;
}, 2000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `object` in your example is `user` to the function and do the actions on it instead `$scope` which is global

Html:

```
  <li class="listItems" ng-repeat="user in userDetails">
    {{user.name}}, {{user.job}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok markAsChecked" ng-click="markAsChecked(user)"></span>
    <span ng-show="user.isLoaderActivated" class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat loader"></span>
  </li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.markAsChecked = function(item) {
console.log("clicked");
item.isLoaderActivated = true;
$timeout(function() {
  item.isLoaderActivated = false;
}, 2000);
```

};